# Problem with integral of the type (x^2-y^2)^a/2 x^2 Exp[-x]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I tried to calculate the following integral using Mathematica
`Integrate[(x^2 - y^2)^(3)/2  x^2 Exp[-x], {x, y, Infinity}]`

The answer was a  conditional expression of the form
`ConditionalExpression[ 24 E^-y (840 + y (840 + y (375 + y (95 + y (14 + y))))),  Re[y] > 0 && Im[y] == 0]`

Can I compute the integral  with Re[y] less than 0?

Answer (score 2):

Or, add the appropriate assumption to `Integrate`:

```
Integrate[(x^2 - y^2)^(3)/2 x^2 Exp[-x], {x, y, Infinity},
     Assumptions -> y < 0]

(*  24 E^-y (840 + y (840 + y (375 + y (95 + y (14 + y)))))  *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback

Comment: I have related question, I tried to compute the following integral Integrate[1/6 Sqrt[x^2 - y^2] x^2 Exp[-x], {x, y, Infinity}] but Mathematica did not give me the answer so how can I compute it ?

Comment: Your second integral is, of course, complex.  If you treat is as a complex line integral along the real axis, the expression would be `Integrate[ ... , {x, -y, y, Infinity}, Assumptions -> y > 0]` .

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you, why there is a conditional expression, but you can do it manually:

```
In[1]:  i = Integrate[(x^2 - y^2)^(3)/2 x^2 Exp[-x], {x, y, b}];
In[2]:  Limit[i,b->Infinity]
Out[2]: 24 E^-y (840 + 840 y + 375 y^2 + 95 y^3 + 14 y^4 + y^5)
```